# change digit color in number picker android

Tags: android, xml, colors, numberpicker

Hi I though that is would be an easy deal but I'm stuck...
I build an aplication with a black background and a number picker.
The digits in the number picker are in black... you can understand the problem...
Because of some unknown reason I could not find any code that can change the color of the digits in the number picker.

Please help me... 
What I tried to do is:

```
<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/day"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing the font colour too in the past and have had no joy. You can however change the background of the slider to a different colour so that the text stands out.

```
android:background="#ffffffff"
```